# Homebrew cannot download from homebrew.bintray.com, gives a curl error: "no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name"

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, homebrew

When I try to install or upgrade any package hosted on `homebrew.bintray.com`, I get the following error:

`curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'homebrew.bintray.com'`

It suggests looking at `https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html`, but if there's a solution on there I don't know enough about curl or ssl to see it.

I have been unable to find anybody else online with this problem--everything I've found has either been server-side issues (which I know this isn't, since I've tested installing the same packages on other machines and they've worked perfectly) or just said to use `curl -k`, which doesn't seem like a wise long-term fix.

The only warning I get running `brew doctor` simply says that `guile@2` is deprecated or disabled.

EDIT:

Reinstalling Homebrew has not worked. Homebrew appears to be working fine; I can install packages not hosted on homebrew.bintray.com (e.g., Adobe Reader).

Attempting to access `https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles` from Safari, I get "This Connection Is Not Private"; when I view the certificate, it is named `*.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com`. Doing this on a computer with working homebrew instead gets a certificate named `*.bintray.com`.

Comment: When you say "other machines" do you mean other Macs? Is brew up to date? Try reinstall brew?

Comment: I tested it on two friends' macs, running the same OS X (11.2.3), brew (3.0.11), and curl (7.64.1). Brew is up-to-date; reinstalling does nothing.

It does appear to be a problem specifically with `homebrew.bintray.com`—I can install, for example, Adobe Reader just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else comes across this issue, this [reply on the Homebrew GitHub issues page](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1248#discussioncomment-595112) was able to fix it BUT requires switching to the development version of Brew.

> It looks like you're being connected elsewhere for some reason. It sounds more like a network-related issue. Are you running a firewall/packet analyser/etc (e.g. Little Snitch)? You might also have a weird DNS setup.
>
> Failing figuring that out, this might work:
>
> ```
> HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=https://ghcr.io/v2/Homebrew/core brew install <formula>
> ```
>
> It's likely that this only works if you're on the development version of brew, though. To switch to it,
>
> ```
> HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER=1 brew update
> ```
>
> I'd recommend this only as a last resort, though, since switching back to the stable version of brew could get complicated.

Comment: Great work! But just so you know I added the text of the linked post here. That is allowed and preferred. Otherwise this is considered a link-only answer and would be down-voted and possibly closed.